# How to get embed value and file name in a directory

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a `docx` file and want to generate a list of picture filenames/unique ids combinations.
Here is the relevant piece of the `docx` file:

```
  <w:drawing>
      <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="2C4CE07B" wp14:editId="12367BBF">
        ...
        ...            
          <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
              <pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:cNvPr id="2" name="ProfileGraph.png" />
                <pic:cNvPicPr />
              </pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:blipFill>
                <a:blip r:embed="rId9">
                  <a:extLst>
```

so I need `rId9` and `ProfileGraph.png` in one directory entry.
I can find the `rId9`:

```
var blipElements = from drawing in drawingElements
                   where drawing.Descendants<A.Blip>().Count() > 0
                   select drawing.Descendants<A.Blip>().First();
```

But I don't know how to get the `cNvPr-elements` belonging to each of the `Blips` in `blipElements`.

I was thinking in the line of

```
 var names = from blip in blipElements
             where blip.Ancestors<Picture>().First<Picture>().Descendants<....>()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
var pics = body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture>();
var result = pics.Select(p => new
    {
        Id = p.BlipFill.Blip.Embed.Value,
        Name = p.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Name.Value
    });
```

Where doc is assumed to be an already opened WordProcessingDocument object.

The result variable will be an IEnumerable of an anonymous type containg Id and Name properties.

I'm not particularly knowledgable on the word processing OpenXML stuff but, in theory, the Embed and Name properties could be null so I suppose you might have to test for null before accessing the '.Value' property.